DevExpress Code Analysis throwing errors during build process in VS2022
I've recently updated to VS2022 and installed the latest version DevEx and I am now getting the errors as illustrated in the screenshot. "Enable and ignore future errors" only applies to current session.

I have tried disabling DevEx Code Analysis but must have disabled the wrong option as the error is still displayed.
My support licence expired a couple of days ago and it'll cost me well over AUD$1200 to find out directly from DevEx so I thought I'd try here.
Any ideas?
